# Match string unless it is inside square brackets

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to adapt the a JQuery zen coding plug in I found to my own uses. One of the issues I'm having is a bug inside the code where something like

```
a[href="google.com"]
```

will expand to

```
 <a href="google.com" class="com"</a>
```

The regex being used by the code is:

```
/(\.[\w-]+)/gi
```

Which I have modified with a look-ahead to see if there is an even number of brackets in front of it.

```
/(\.[\w-]+)(?=([^\]]*\][^\]]*\])*[^\]]*$)/gi
```

I've used regex testers and it seems to work, but when using javascript `.match()`, it is returning ".com" as a match inside the above string.

The below response has solved the bug in question but has created a new one. Now:

```
a.class[href="google.com"]
```

is not resolving to

http://jsfiddle.net/sA9sQ/

**EDIT:**
I accepted the answer below because it got me where I needed to go. The final regex turned out to be `/(\.[\w-]+)(?=([^\]]*\][^\]]*\])*[^\]]*\.[\w-]+)/gi`

Comment: `/gi` what is it? /g is used for all! but for what /gi is used?

Comment: @AspiringAqib `i` = case-insensitive. No effect here, but still a good practice just in case.

Comment: @JanDvorak can you give an example?

Comment: Note that you're counting closing brackets only. Maybe you should look if the next opening bracket or the next closing bracket is closer.

Comment: @AspiringAqib `/a/i.test("A") //true`

Comment: Note that `\w` includes the hyphen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving the look-ahead to the front of the regex, like this:

```
/(?=([^\]]*\][^\]]*\])*[^\]]*$)(\.[\w-]+)/gi
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks! Can you explain why by any chance? I'm pretty green when it comes to regex.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski this will modify the place where the assertion occurs. No idea why it changes the outcome here, though.

Comment: I am not 100% sure, but I believe it has to do with the order it evaluates the expression.  In yours, it evaluates `(\.[\w-]+)` first, finds a match, then evaluates `(?=([^\]]*\][^\]]*\])*[^\]]*$)` followed by no other search. Since that is also a valid match, it is effectively just searching for `(\.[\w-]+)`.  By moving the look-ahead to the front, it now evaluates the look-ahead first, then checks to see if the next expression is found right after the look-ahead.

Comment: Sorry, I just saw the comment.  I'm glad you got the answer though!